# "Suspend to swap" encryption

Tags: suspend, encryption, swap, hibernate

I have enabled "suspend to swap". The swap partition is protected because I have enabled full disk encryption (standard luks and lvm layout). However the swap partition is not protected after resume. Sensitive data could be available for a long time (since my system hardly swaps due to plenty of memory).

I can wipe the swap area with `sswap` (the secure swap wiper from the secure_deletion toolkit). But this process is tedious.

I just read this

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/power/swsusp.html

(Jump to *What is this ‘Encrypt suspend image’ for?*)

And I am wondering how I could enable this in my case?

---

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 (but I am flexible and will switch to any version, if that solves this problem).

---

Copy and paste from the link above

First of all: [Encrypt suspend image] is not a replacement for dm-crypt encrypted swap. It cannot protect your computer while it is suspended. Instead it does protect from leaking sensitive data after resume from suspend.

Think of the following: you suspend while an application is running that keeps sensitive data in memory. The application itself prevents the data from being swapped out. Suspend, however, must write these data to swap to be able to resume later on. Without suspend encryption your sensitive data are then stored in plaintext on disk. This means that after resume your sensitive data are accessible to all applications having direct access to the swap device which was used for suspend. If you don’t need swap after resume these data can remain on disk virtually forever. Thus it can happen that your system gets broken in weeks later and sensitive data which you thought were encrypted and protected are retrieved and stolen from the swap device. To prevent this situation you should use ‘Encrypt suspend image’.

During suspend a temporary key is created and this key is used to encrypt the data written to disk. When, during resume, the data was read back into memory the temporary key is destroyed which simply means that all data written to disk during suspend are then inaccessible so they can’t be stolen later on. The only thing that you must then take care of is that you call ‘mkswap’ for the swap partition used for suspend as early as possible during regular boot. This asserts that any temporary key from an oopsed suspend or from a failed or aborted resume is erased from the swap device.

As a rule of thumb use encrypted swap to protect your data while your system is shut down or suspended. Additionally use the encrypted suspend image to prevent sensitive data from being stolen after resume.

Answer (score 0):

Read the warnings in the text you posted above - the TL&DR is that you probably don't want to do this. Instead, use LUKS to always encrypt your swap. There are various ways to accomplish this, the easiest probably having your root+swap on an LVM physical volume which itself is LUKS encrypted.